# Using Aspect-Orient-Programming in Java with annotation-labeled methods

Tags: java, annotations, aop

I have a JAX-RS based ([RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy)) REST server that uses Java annotations to label resource methods with URLs, etc. For example, a methods can have the annotations

```
@javax.ws.rs.GET
@javax.ws.rs.Path("/users/{user_id}")
public Response getUser(...)
```

and will be called automatically when a client calls the `GET /users/1234 HTTP/1.1` URL.

I am finding that my resource methods have more and more "common" logic that must be executed with every method: logging, security checks, query parameter validation, etc. I believe that this calls for Aspect-Orient-Programming (AOP), but I have not used this technology before. If I use one of the AOP frameworks, will my annotation "labeling" be preserved so that the JAX-RS driver can find my resource methods? Which AOP frameworks will work with my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) fulfills your requirements: AspectJ can intercept calls or executions of annotated methods without changing or removing the annotations.

For instance, we used AspectJ on JPA entities and these classes were still visible by Hibernate.